# Apple Push Notification not received when updating a pass

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, passbook, wallet

I am having some passes in my iPhone wallet. When passes are updated I am not receiving APN on my iPhone. Can you please help me to understand what can be reason? Below is the iPhone logs retrieved by the Mac console.

Thanks

```
default 16:54:57.540688 +0400   passd   Signature validation: succeeded
default 16:54:57.586711 +0400   passd   Color sampled for lightness: 0.634640.
default 16:54:57.833743 +0400   passd   Color sampled for lightness: 0.634640.
default 16:54:57.959896 +0400   passd   Begin delaying exit: AddUbiquitousCard (3)
default 16:54:57.960004 +0400   passd   inserting ubiquitous version of pass: <private>
default 16:54:57.960057 +0400   passd   Write options: 8 -- URL: <private> -- purposeID: 057760F0-09BC-4C80-86F6-7A4A2600633B -- claimID: D5639FC0-B5CD-4B6F-8089-4801B0C34F14
default 16:54:57.960286 +0400   passd   Updating Pass: <private>

default 16:54:57.962248 +0400   passd   Claim D5639FC0-B5CD-4B6F-8089-4801B0C34F14 granted in client
default 16:54:57.962304 +0400   passd   Claim D5639FC0-B5CD-4B6F-8089-4801B0C34F14 invoked in client
default 16:54:57.962805 +0400   passd   copying <private> to <private>
default 16:54:57.982826 +0400   passd   Begin delaying exit: com.apple.passd.passbookBackgroundFetch.coalesce (4)
default 16:54:57.987912 +0400   passd   Updating badge count to 0
default 16:54:57.988099 +0400   passd   Beginning spotlight index of 1 passes.
default 16:54:57.991779 +0400   passd   Inserting User Notification: [<private>] into Pass User Notification Center: [<private>]
default 16:54:57.991885 +0400   passd   Cannot insert User Notification: <private> in Notification Center: <private> as it is not valid.
default 16:54:57.997962 +0400   passd   Spotlight index of passes completed with error (null).
default 16:54:58.006208 +0400   passd   End delaying exit: AddUbiquitousCard (3)
default 16:54:58.008358 +0400   passd   Field Detector: Disabling field detection...
default 16:54:58.008485 +0400   passd   Begin delaying exit: WrittenCardRevocationCheck (4)
default 16:54:58.008529 +0400   passd   Field Detector: Disabled field detection.
default 16:54:58.046179 +0400   passd   Deactivating task <private>
default 16:54:58.046637 +0400   passd   No tasks remain in PDNetworkTaskManager 0x103949ab0
default 16:54:58.046883 +0400   passd   PDNetworkTaskManager 0x103949ab0: Released power assertion: <private> (36353)
default 16:54:58.047114 +0400   passd   End delaying exit: ActiveTasks (3)
default 16:54:58.047770 +0400   passd   Removing Scheduled Activity: PDNetworkTaskManagerActivateEligibleTasksActivityIdentifier for Client: <private>
default 16:54:58.048135 +0400   passd   Begin delaying exit: Archiving Scheduled Activities (4)
default 16:54:58.048370 +0400   passd   Scheduling Activate Tasks Activity with a start date of: Tue Jun  4 16:56:03 2019
default 16:54:58.050808 +0400   passd   removing all entries config 0x100f65d10
default 16:54:58.051127 +0400   passd   TIC TCP Conn Cancel [73:0x1027aae40]
default 16:54:58.051846 +0400   passd   [C73 Hostname#fddb075a:443 tcp, url hash: 15f357dd, tls] cancel
default 16:54:58.052171 +0400   passd   [C73 Hostname#fddb075a:443 tcp, url hash: 15f357dd, tls] cancelled
```

Comment: What platform are you using to send the push notification?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your API Handler works by HTTP make sure that you are turned on the setting something like "Allow Http while Wallet testing" on iPhone where your Pass installed. You will need HTTPS on production
2. Make sure that your API Handler has right Interface (URI path, incoming parameters, etc.)
3. Make sure that your iPhone where your Pass installed has access to API Handler (security, reachability)

The easiest way to check it: setup proxy on your iPhone and send all traffic from it to PC/Mac (for example using Charles Proxy). You will be able to see all requests that the device sends to your API Handler.